# Deploy says disk full when the disk is not actually full

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy an update to our rails app on a digital ocean box. When I run `cap deploy` I get the errors:

```
error: file write error (No space left on device)
fatal: unable to write sha1 file
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

When I run `df` I see that we are only using 15% of our disk space:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       41151808 5500720  33537664  15% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1014128       4   1014124   1% /dev
tmpfs             205000     360    204640   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1024980       0   1024980   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
```

`df -i` reveals:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      2621440 176278 2445162    7% /
none            256245      2  256243    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            253532    402  253130    1% /dev
tmpfs           256245    325  255920    1% /run
none            256245      1  256244    1% /run/lock
none            256245      1  256244    1% /run/shm
none            256245      3  256242    1% /run/user
```

I've tried deleting log files and rebooting the box with no luck. Any ideas on why it thinks our disk is full?

Comment: Check your inodes with `df -i`

Comment: @dan-klasson I just updated my question with the output.

Comment: @Deekor - I was faced same issue but after I upgrading my DO plan and purchase higher plan, it resolved. You can upgrade with higher plan using this simple steps https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-resize-your-droplets-on-digitalocean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was actually coming from the database server - which was full.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue here after several failed attempts to deploy with `capistrano3`.

`df -i` did indeed indicate high usage in my case on the app server, but I was able to resolve it by clearing out old releases with `cap ENVIRONMENT deploy:clean`

This answer may be helpful for others that end up here and wonder where their space has gone; especially if something's gone hay wire with previous deployments, they may be taking up an egregious amount of space or inodes. more likely.